# How to add on-line CSS reference in Apache Wicket Web Applications?

Tags: html, css, wicket, wicket-1.5, wicket-1.6

Currently I am using this code to add a CSS resource to my Wicket Web Application,

```
this.add(new CssResourceRefernce(FontAwesomeStyleSheetResourceReference.class, "css/font-awesome.css"));
```

I want to add this same CSS file as a on-line resource to my application. Using HTML I can do ti like this,

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

What is the 'Wicket' way of doing this task?

Answer (score 5):

In Wicket 6.x, you can override renderHead() to include a CSS resource via URL like this:

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response){
  response.render(CSSReferenceHeaderItem.forUrl("url_to_your_css.css"));
}
```

Comment: I would make it a CSSReferenceHeaderItem (or CSSUrlReferenceHeaderItem) instead of a javascript one. Also, make sure you call super.renderHead(response).

Comment: Yeah CSSReferenceHeaderItem is what I meant...thanks for the hint.

Comment: Typo in the example above. Class is actually "CssReferenceHeaderItem" with small ss in Css :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like @Tom did it or what you are looking after is the [UrlResourceReference](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/request/resource/UrlResourceReference.html) that is

> A ResourceReference that can be used to point to a resource by using an Url. For example to a resource residing in a CDN (Content Delivering Network) or context relative one.